setting up a python websockets server on a host like render.com
I have some server code written in python websockets (the server purely serves websockets) that I have tested and works on localhost. I am trying to set up a server on render.com with this code but i am having problems. The URL that render.com gives me is something like https://sample-site.onrender.com. The server code has a line that goes
start_server = websockets.serve(main, "0.0.0.0", 8765)

and it did give me a Your service is live  message in the console. I am having trouble connecting to it with my clientside code (also using python websockets package)
websockets.connect('ws://sample-site.onrender.com:8765')

upon attempting to connect, the server side console does not display anything and I time out on the client side.
The code I tested was only with ws (not wss) so I tried connecting with the url as ws instead of wss but it doesnt work. Both of these returned a timeout error when trying to connect.
error reads:
"C:\Users\...\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 729, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

which lead to the program timing out when connecting.
If I had to guess I would say it has something to do with wss messing me up since wss doesnt work on my clientside tests but Im not sure which way to fix it: downgrade from wss to ws or upgrade my code to handle wss. Help with a direction to go is appreciated

Do you have to configure a firewall to allow your ports through?

@TimRoberts I have not. I am not sure how to allow ports through the firewall on render though. The console on render does say Detected service running on port 8765 and it links me to https://docs.render.com/web-services#port-binding. The example they provide is in js (? i think) and im not sure what is the equivalent in python.
Edit: i see i have to set an env variable. im looking at it right now

@TimRoberts I added the port variable in the env and it still doesnt work. it does not show the Detected service running on port 8765 message anymore though
